# Django2のデータベース設定(ENGINE VALUE)とHeroku管理画面ログイン

Tags: django, heroku, postgresql

Django２.0でブログのプロジェクトを作成しています。データベースはデフォルトのSQlite3からPostgreSQLに変更し,Herokuにデプロイしました。
Herokuサイト上の管理画面からログインできなくなったため、解消方法をご教示いただきたく投稿させていただきました。

行った作業ですが、サイトを色々調べ、settings.pyの

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

これを

```
import dj_database_url
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
db_from_env = dj_database_url.config()
DATABASES = {
        'default': dj_database_url.config()
}
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
```

このように置き換えデプロイしたところ,`$ heroku open`で正常にサイトが表示されました。
デプロイする前に`$ python manage.py createsuperuser`でスーパーユーザーの
アカウントを作成し、パスワードも設定しました。
ローカル環境ではこのログイン情報が有効で、管理画面からログインしてブログ投稿もできます。

ところがhttps:*****.herokuapp.com/admin
から管理画面でログインしようとしたところ、ローカルで有効だったユーザー情報ではログインできません。
再び色々と調べ、改めてスーパーユーザーアカウントを作る必要があるとたどり着きました。
そしてまた`$ python manage.py createsuperuser`を実行したところ、

> settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value.

↑このエラーが出てきました。

まだ試していないのですが、DATABASESの記述を以下にすれば,再び
create superuserが実行でき、Herokuサイトから管理画面でログインできるのでしょうか。

```
import dj_database_url
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
db_from_env = dj_database_url.config()
DATABASES = {
        'default':{  
　　　　　　　'ENGINE':'django.db.backends.postgresql'
            'NAME': dj_database_url.config()
         }
}
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
```

あるいは、他の原因や方法があればご教示頂けますと幸いです。
Herokuのダッシュボードから　PostgreSQLの設定が何か必要なのでしょうか。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

自己解決しました。初歩的なコマンドミスによりcreatesuperuserができていませんでした。

正しくは
$ heroku run python manage.py createsuperuser
でしたが、うっかり heroku runをつけ忘れ、
$ python manage.py createsupseuser
を何度も実行していました。

無事にheroku.app/adminからログインできるようになりました。
大変お騒がせいたしました。